# SCNNode lookAt is facing the reversed direction

Tags: swift, xcode, unity-game-engine, scenekit

I have a custom skeleton 3d Model I got from Unity, converted to dae, and imported to XCode.

In Unity, transform that lookAt, performs as expected.
But in XCode, it is looking at reversed direction. It seems, that orientation and/or rotation of the SCNNode got reversed.

For example,
in Swift

Test 1

1. Skeleton is at (0,0,0)
2. call lookAt (3, 0 , 0)

Result for Test 1
Skeleton is facing negative x direction. And back is facing positive direction (3).

Test 2

1. Skeleton is at (0,0,0)
2. call lookAt (3, 10, 0)

Result for Test 2
Skeleton is facing negative x direction
Skeleton is facing negative y direction

Back is facing positive x direction (3).
Back is facing positive y direction (10).

I dont know a lot about SceneKit and Unity. I used https://anyconv.com/fbx-to-dae-converter/ to convert my Unity FBX Asset to dae

Thanks in advance

Comment: you should probably check your model in i.ex. Blender for correct orientation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get your models oriented before you use them.  Once they are set, that's what you get and you can't do anything about it.

See my answer here: 56183036

It's dated, but I think it still works.